# How to unhide rows in Excel by value within a column based on a drop down list in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to show hidden rows on a sheet based on what is chosen in a drop down box. The values are in column 2 and are names. There is a drop down list in a cell (C9) below all the hidden rows where you can choose a name and I would like the row where the name is contained to appear.

So far I have code for a Macro that can unhide a row with a given name :

```
Sub Mike()
    BeginRow = 1
    EndRow = 6
    ChkCol = 2

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "Mike" Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

And then I can make a Macro to call upon each individual Macro if the value in the drop down cell is a name. However the list of names is going to change so I need a Macro that is independent of names. I have tried to replace the code so that the value of was what is in cell C9, but although the Macro runs without any errors it also doesn't do anything.

```
Sub ShowRows()
    BeginRow = 1
    EndRow = 6
    ChkCol = 2

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = C9 Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

Comment: `If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Range("C9").Value Then` Your syntax is off. If you turned on Option Explicit it would have flagged an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C9 doesn't make sense like this to VBA. It assumes it is an empty variable.
You need the cell that is called "C9":

```
Range("C9")
```

And you need the Value from that cell (not, for example, the background or border colour):

```
Range("C9").Value
```

So try:

```
If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Range("C9").Value Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Mike()
BeginRow = 1
EndRow = 6
ChkCol = 2

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
    If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Range("C9").Value Then
        Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next RowCnt
```

End Sub